# Date formula Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Oi,

I'm trying to add a new column to my Power Query containing a fixed text & date (MMYYYY) and i keep getting errors while doing so.

Example of what i need is : "TEST 032022" --> Test is Fixed ; 03 is formula ; 2022 is formula

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? What is the error? Where does the date come from? based on today?

Comment: I'm already stuck at :
'Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())&" "&(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())'

Error i'm getting is :  We cannot apply operator & to types Number and Text.
They do work seperately but i get an error when i try to merge them (If that's even the correct way?)

Comment: Update: I've managed to fix above by adding a Text.From ..

Just have to keep digging how to fix the month to 03 (instead of 3) and add a fixed text..

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the Numbers into text, using the [Date.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-totext) function or [Number.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-totext)

So for your MM you would need some thing like this, assuming you have a date column

```
Number.ToText(Date.Month([Date]), "00")
```

Which gives months 01 to 12

Or

```
Number.ToText(Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()), "00")
```

Using the current date time "03"

For your example you would need

```
"TEST " & Number.ToText(Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()), "00") & Number.ToText(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

Which outputs TEST 032022

[image]